# Hide Links In Forums

Tags: php

I've tried to hide link from none registered members, the BBcode works and it hides, but the HTML code doesn't work.

For example,

```
[link=http://www.brandbucket.com/]Brand Bucket[/link]
```

This hides well.

On the other hand..

```
<a href="http://www.char5.com/" target="_blank">http://www.char5.com</a>
```

This doesn't hide at all, the hyperlink works fine.

Here's the code below for any help please, thanks.

```
    $text = preg_replace("/\[file\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/file\]/is", $rep, $text);
$text = preg_replace("/\[link\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/link\]/is", $rep, $text);
$text = preg_replace("/\[url\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/is", $rep, $text);
$text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[^ \"\n\r\t<,]*)#is", "\\1".$rep, $text);
$text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n \]])((www|ftp)\.[\w+-]+?\.[\w+\-.]*(?(?=/)(/.+?(?=\s|,\s))|(?=\W)))#is", "\\1".$rep, $text);
```

Comment: None of your regex patterns look like they even try to match HTML anchor tags, though I wouldn't suggest you try. Probably worth you looking at [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DomDocument) and XPath.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use an `if else` statement and `echo` the elements on to the page if conditions are met.

For example on my website I have a logout button. It only shows if a user is logged in.

```
<?php
    if(/*user is logged in*/) {
        echo 'This is where the element code is placed';
    }
    else {
        //user is not logged in so don't echo the element
    }
?>
```

This php block will be placed inside the container element where the element you want to show would normally be. Note that if the `else` section of the statement is empty you can leave it out.

This can also work for a specific id or class you want to apply to an element (like changing the background colour of a div) by inserting the block where the id or class definition is.

```
<div id="testdiv" <?php if(/*condition*/) {echo 'class="addedclass"';} ?> ><div>
```